# display alert message onReceive method of broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, service, android-service

in my application images are uploaded on server in `IntentService` after all images are uploaded. intent service sends broadcast, and `onReceive` method receives response and displays appropriate alert message. But if my app is in pause or other application are activated and after my application opens, alert message is not displayed. If my app is in foreground it will display alert message. How do I solve this problem, should I used `boolean` shared preferences in **IntentService** when download complete check boolean value onresume method and alert display when user open my app?

```
/*getting response from service*/
    BroadcastReceiver br=new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("recived", "service broadcast");
        String response=intent.getStringExtra("response");
        if(response.equals("null"))
        {
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Note_Signature_activity.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Connection Time Out");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setMessage("Connection Time Out Please Check Your Internet Connection");
            alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
            alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            final_submit_button.setClickable(true);
                            pb.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
        }
        else
        {
            final_submit_button.setClickable(true);
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Note_Signature_activity.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Success");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setMessage("Congratulations Successfully Submitted!");
            alert.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
            alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            final_submit_button.setClickable(false);
                            pb.dismiss();
                            clear_main_history();
                            Intent select_trip_section=new Intent(Note_Signature_activity.this, SelectTripActivity.class);
                            select_trip_section.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(select_trip_section);
                        }
                    });
            alert.show();
        }
    }
};
/**/
```

Comment: It's would be much better if you tray down your download progress on notification tray.

Comment: but how can i figure out that service complete it's uploading process so when user click on notification i can show the alert dialog

Comment: As you said you `BroadCast` and receive the `tResponse` when uploading is completed through your `Service`. At that point you can catch the `BroadCast` and display whatever message you want to be popped out on tray or on your `Activity` of Application

Comment: but actually when my application is on background BrodcastReceiver onReceive method not called

Comment: Solved it using sharedpreferences boolean Value after download complete in service set boolean prefrences and check in onResume method of Activity